# ¿Una función pude retornar una TABLA como resultado en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Quiero crear una función en la cual al ingresar el ID de un cliente devuelva la cantidad de productos facturados ordenados en una tabla como en este ejemplo en SQL Server:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Prod_fact_Cte (@id_cte int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT cliente.id_clie, articulo.id_art, articulo.nom_art ,SUM(det_fact.cant_art) AS 'Tot Prod Fact' 
    FROM articulo  
        JOIN det_fact  ON det_fact.id_art = articulo.id_art
        JOIN factura  ON factura.id_fact = det_fact.id_fact
        JOIN cliente ON factura.id_clie = cliente.id_clie
    WHERE cliente.id_clie = @id_cte
    GROUP BY cliente.id_clie, articulo.id_art, articulo.nom_art
);
```

Leí por algunos foros que en MySQL esto no era posible ¿Es verdad?
Y de ser así de que otra manera podría hacerse en MySQL.

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo haces con una consulta plana? Sería mas rápido solo con un `SELECT`

Comment: No existe en mySql, pero puedes retornarlo en  un procedure o simplemente utilizar una subconsulta o en función de la versión de mySql el operador LATERAL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869221/cross-outer-apply-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `MySql` lamentablemente las funciones no pueden retornar un resultado tipo tabla al menos hasta la versión 8.0 ([ver documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)). Una función solo permite retornar los [tipos de datos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) habituales que maneja la base, una tabla o recordset no es un tipo en sí sino una colección de otros tipos de datos.

Lo único especial que permite una función que retorna una tabla en SQL SERVER es la posibilidad de: (a) pasarle parámetros y (b) usarla en una clase `SELECT`, infelizmente no hay nada similar en MYSQL, lo que más se acercaría

1. Un [procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html): Puedes pasarle parámetros, pero estas obligado a que el SP inserte el resultado de la consulta en una tabla temporal para reutilizar los datos luego.
2. Una [vista](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html). Que no puedes parle parámetros pero al menos podrías usar directamente en una clausula `SELECT`